# LocalNotification setId() behavior [codenameone]

Tags: codenameone

Is LocalNotification Id suppose to be displayed in ToastBar?

I created a Local notification:

```
LocalNotification ln = new LocalNotification();
                ln.setId("geofence entered");
                ln.setAlertTitle("Welcome");
                ln.setAlertBody("Please proceed to the building");
                Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(ln,
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE);
```

It fires properly and shows me a notification with correct Title and Body. However, if I click on it, when it opens the app - the `Id` "geofence entered" is displayed in `ToastBar`. If I remove `.setId("geofence entered")`, the notification is not shown and I get an error:

```
2021-07-13 17:15:40.009 21809-21809/io.jarvisapp.app E/Codename One: background location error
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Notification ID must be set
        at com.codename1.ui.Display.scheduleLocalNotification(Display.java:4804)
        at io.jarvisapp.app.geofence.GeofenceListenerImpl.onEntered(GeofenceListenerImpl.java:131)
```

where line 131 is  `Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(ln, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE);`

How can I not display the id in ToastBar?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: We don't show the notification in a `ToastBar` I think this is something you're showing in the callback code.

Comment: The notification is displayed properly with Title and Body. It's just when you open an app in foreground after clicking on the notification, the `ToastBar` with the notification ID is displayed too. I didn't add any custom code with `LocalNotificationCallback` class - all I added is the code that I included in question. Am I missing what callback code you are talking about?

Comment: I suggest commenting out all usages of ToastBar in your code and seeing  if this appears. We don't show a toast on local notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece of code that was causing the issue was found, thanks to @Shai comment about the callback code.
I completely forgot that I implemented `LocalNotificationCallback` with the following method in my main class:

```
@Override
public void localNotificationReceived(String notificationId) {
   GeneralUtil.showToastBarMessage(notificationId,3000,0);
}
```